# What's the suitable way to implement identity in microservice?

Tags: authentication, authorization, microservices

I'm trying to find a suitable way to implement the identification approach in microservices. I would be happy if you help me to cover my questions:
 - How can we register services and external applications as an identified service?
 - How can we authenticate and authorize them when they want to connect together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you are looking for the ways to authenticate the clients that try to access your microservice, if it is so I think you can use OAuth2 Client Credentials flow. Deploy an OAuth2 authorization(AZ) server. OAuth2 AZ server registers your clients and provides them clientid and client secret.
When the client wants to access your microservice it first authenticates itself to OAuth2 AZ server with clientid and secret, and gets an access token. This access token is presented to your microservice which can then determine the access control to provide the response accordingly.
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm trying to find a way to adapt microservices with OAuth for example, I don't know how to integrate between microservices and OAuth? Messaging , RPC or other ways

Comment: I believe it is a synchronous call. Do a tunnel call with https; use any http client library.